# change imageview in the whole app

Tags: android, interface, imageview, global-variables

I have an app that is a chat, while you navigate in the App, you can receive a message, if you receive it the icon "message" changes to a new one (that new icon tells the user that he has a new message).

while you are navigating in the app I created different Activities that have the same footer (include other layout)

So what I want is, how I can change the state of the message to new message in all the activities when I receive the message?

I thought about creating an interface with one method that checks if the activity has been created and if is, just change the imageView, but I think there is a better way.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider creating a interface that have methods based on different kind of updates.
For example `onNewMessage(Message)` and similar. Then you have let the implementors register themselves with the service that determines when these events occur. So when a message is received the service will go through the list of registered implementors and post the update.
The implementor would in this case update it's imageview.

Don't forget to also unregister when reasonable and so forth.